# Como ignorar um campo duplicado e seguir com a inserção?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho um arquivo `txt` que estou extraindo informações e nele as informações estão repetidas 6 vezes, o que me insere no banco de dados o mesmo registro também 6 vezes.

Setei `UNIQUE` para um número único a cada registro no banco de dados mysql mas ao tentar rodar o sql que insere os dados, dá um `Entrada '120000001016' duplicada para a chave 'SQ_CANDIDATO'` e o processo de inserção é terminado.

Como eu poderia solucionar este problema inserindo apenas uma vez cada registro no banco sem ter que tratar o `txt`?

```
foreach ($itens as $item) {

$dados      = explode(';', $item);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO VOT_CAND_MUN_ZONA VALUES ( 

                        '',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[0], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[1], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[2], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[3], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[4], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[5], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[6], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[7], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[8], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[9], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[10], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[11], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[12], '"'))."', <---- UNIQUE
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[13], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[14], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[15], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[16], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[17], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[18], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[19], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[20], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[21], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[22], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[23], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[24], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[25], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[26], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[27], '"'))."',
                        '".utf8_decode(trim($dados[28], '"'))."'

)") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: É um insert com vários values então?

Comment: Está dentro de um **foreach**

Comment: Remova o `die` assim ele passa para a proxima linha do array e faz o insert seguinte.

Comment: Perfeito @rray coloquei unique mas esqueci de remover o **die**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O processo de inserção é para porque você está chamado `die()` caso o `mysql_query` falhe, isso faz o script terminar de forma parecida como um [exit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php). Removendo o `die()` o erro ainda vai acontecer porém o proximo item do array será avaliado na consulta.

O ideal é gravar os erros de `mysql_error()` em um log a parte.

Answer (score 3):

Use a palavra-chave `IGNORE` para ignorar eventuais erros (incluindo linhas duplicadas) na sua query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO ...
```

Da [documentação do MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html):

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are ignored. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row is discarded and no error occurs. Ignored errors may generate warnings instead, although duplicate-key errors do not.
>
> IGNORE has a similar effect on inserts into partitioned tables where no partition matching a given value is found. Without IGNORE, such INSERT statements are aborted with an error; however, when INSERT IGNORE is used, the insert operation fails silently for the row containing the unmatched value, but any rows that are matched are inserted. For an example, see Section 19.2.2, “LIST Partitioning”.
>
> Data conversions that would trigger errors abort the statement if IGNORE is not specified. With IGNORE, invalid values are adjusted to the closest values and inserted; warnings are produced but the statement does not abort. You can determine with the mysql_info() C API function how many rows were actually inserted into the table.